# Automation of Powershell script, that invokes a Python script, doesn't work (via Task Scheduler)

Tags: python, windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to create a bunch of automations on my PC with Windows, and I encountered some obstacles while trying to automate a Powershell script with Windows Task Scheduler.

Right now, I have managed to set up a Task Scheduler to perform an actual script, but despite the whole script working as intended when I start it manually, it doesn't work right while invoked via task scheduler.

The Powershell script is very simple, it is meant to invoke a certain Python script. I also created a log transcript for testing purposes.

```
python dataset_creator.py --to_import yes --to_export yes
Start-Transcript -Path "<path>\transcript0.txt"
```

While invoked manually, the Python script works, but via Task Scheduler, the only working part is a transcript creation (ergo - no Python script is running). The Task Scheduler informs me itself that the task executed properly. This is how I set up the action:

```
Program: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Arguments: -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\<path>\powershell_script.ps1"
```

As for now, I have set it on a SYSTEM account, I have tried to set it on my user admin account, but it doesn't work as well.

Could you suggest the potential issues? I scrolled through several articles and nothing works. I also tried to skip the Powershell part (aka - set up the task relying only on a Python task), but it didn't work so far, and I also initially wanted to insert a number of Python scripts invokations into a single Powershell file.

I am also open to some Windows Task Scheduler alternatives suggestions.

Comment: Maybe the python environment (path variable, etc) is only set for your user and not present for SYSTEM or your admin account (profiles). Try using full paths in your script.

Comment: ZivkoK, thanks for a suggestion. I have tried adding a variable in Powershell  $env:path="$env:Path;C:\<path>", along with changing localizations, and it doesn't work so far. If I find any other solution, I'll let you know

Comment: You probably want to start the transcript _before_ invoking `python`

Comment: I have managed to find a solution in a meantime - I revised ZivkoK steps, but also added full path into python file that I wanted to invoke.